# React can not find module

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript, react-native

After I create my react project with

> `npx create-react-app`

my-app I run

> `npm start`

and get this error as you can see below in the image

node version: 12.16.1

npm version: 6.13.4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOk88.png)

I will be grateful if you show me a solution!

and this is my package.js file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CMuV.jpg

Comment: Can you please run npm install and then npm start to check if it works?

Comment: Can you add your package.json here ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/v8yeKrR this is my package.js

Comment: try removing @testing libraries and hit npm install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Then reinstall `npm i`
then start `npm start`

Comment: After npx create-react-app I don't have any package-lock.json file

Comment: Then ignore that step. :)

Answer (score 3):

These kind of problems could be happening when clashing react modules. Delete `node_module` folder and `package-lock.json` file. Then run again `npm  install` and `npm start`.

Answer (score 2):

Use yarn create react-app my-app , cd my-app ,npm start .Now download all the dependencies form npm or yarn. It will work.

Comment: Still getting the same error but thanks for helping